# I try to send JSON data from node js server to jquery client, but it does not work

Tags: jquery, node.js

I try to send JSON data from node js server to jquery client, but it does not work.

I want send JSON data to display information in table format in html.

Ajax can work but at success of ajax function it displays nothing and browser say nothing wrong.

server side code

```
var url = require("url");
var http = require('http');
var req = require('ajax-request');
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/myaction', async function (req, res) {
    async function next_func(req, res) {
        var st = req.body.status;

        if (st != 's') {
            await tdb(req);
        }
        var dataJson = await show();
        return dataJson;
    }

    dataJson = await next_func(req, res);
    res.status(200);
    res.contentType('application/json');
    return res.send(dataJson);

});
```

client side code

```
$.fn.ajaxShow = function (st) {
    xhrct = $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            status: st
        },
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8081/myaction',
        success: function (data) {
            $('#tb').empty();
            if (data != null) {
                var fotoData = $.parseJSON(data);
                $(fotoData).each(function (i, obx) {
                    $('#tb').append('<tr>')
                        .append('<td>' + obx.detail + '</td>')
                        .append('<td>' + obx.status + '</td>')
                        .append('<td>' + obx.subject + '</td>')
                        .append('</tr>');
                });
            }
        }
    });
}

This is my show()
async function show(){
var con = mysql.createConnection({
host: "127.0.0.1",
user: "root",
password: "aaaaaaaa",
database: "doto"
}); 
var myJson=null;
var sql ="select * from task_list";
result= "";

await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
con.connect((err, connection) => {
    if (err) return reject(err)
    con.query(sql, (err, rows, fields) => {
         if (err) return reject(err)
         resolve(
             rows.forEach( (row) => { 
             result= result+ "{ \"detail\":\""+ row.details + "\", \"status\":\"" + row.status + "\", \"subject\":\"" + row.subject + "\"},";

              })     
         )
    })
  })
})
result =  result.substring(0, result.length - 1);
myJson = JSON.parse(result);
console.log("myJson"+myJson);
console.log(typeof myJson);
return  myJson;
}
```

I include my function show() and now I just want to display my data from database before tdb().

Comment: Hi Taanyapon Welcom to stack overflow, Try to maintain the code format when posting the code

Comment: are you able to print dataJson @ server side

Comment: Is `dataJson` a string or an object? What does `console.log(typeof dataJson)` show if you place it right before the `res.send(dataJson);`? Is the `success` callback really called?

Comment: my dataJson now is an object already but it still display nothing - I don't understand the success callback is really called how. Is it means callback at nodejs

Comment: can you please post the code of show and tdb functions?
Btw usind bodyParser.json and express.json is kinda the same (express.json uses bodyParser in it's implemantation)

Comment: Moreover, you mentioned that your data in an Object.

Comment: – dima golovin  I try typeof myJson and dataJson they return objects and I try to add code at client  error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  alert("errorThrown: "+errorThrown); } but errorThrown is null